# How does the VBA IsMissing function work under the hood?

Tags: vba, com, ole, variant

According to the docs:

> IsMissing does not work on simple data types (such as Integer or
> Double) because, unlike Variants, they don't have a provision for a
> "missing" flag bit

But in the [`tagVARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) struct I don't see anything about a flag that can be set, I was wondering if the vartype embeds this info like how it embeds ByRef with VT_BYREF (what does `VT_RESERVED` mean?) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[missing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/passing-parameters)" variant is a VARIANT with the `vt` member (VARTYPE) set to `VT_ERROR` and the `scode` member set to `DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND` (0x80020004).

Comment: The link, isn't that DISPPARAMS structure only for late-bound code like callbyname where all the args are variant?

Comment: @Greedo - IsMissing function definition: *"Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an optional Variant argument has been passed to a procedure."*. VT_ERROR + DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND  is the special "missing" variant value. (and BTW .NET is of course consistent with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-objects#marshaling-system-types-to-variant)